# partical violin sticks out of test tube, how to stop it?

Tags: objects, particles, collision

I have a test tube, in it, it has a ParticleSetting and the object is a violin but the head of the violin is sticking out of the test tube body and I want it to collide the hole thing with the test tube.

What do I have to do so it wont stick out?

[image: Violin sticking out of the test tube]

Comment: Do you have any physics enabled?

Comment: my physics is fluid type and a little bit of damp.

Comment: I mean, do you have the test tube set as a collision object?
Share your .blend file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/